# How to convert XmlNode into XElement?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an old `XmlNode`-based code. but the simplest way to solve my current task is to use `XElement` and LINQ-to-XML. The only problem is that there is no direct or obvious method for converting a `XmlNode` to a `XElement` in .NET Framework.

So for starters, I want to implement a method that receives a `XmlNode` instance and converts it to a `XElement` instance.

How can I implement this conversion?

Comment: Are all of your `XmlNode` instances `XmlElement` instances?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, all the `XmlNode` instances are `XmlElement` instances.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Sorry, not all the `XmlNode` instances are `XmlElement` instances. They might be, for example, `XmlComment` instances.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var xElem = XElement.Load( xmlElement.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree() );
```

There are two problems with *xmlElement.InnerXml* used in other answer,

**1-** You will loose the *root* element (Of course, it can be handled easily)

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<root> <sub>aaa</sub> </root>");
var xElem1 = XElement.Load(doc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree());
var xElem2 = XElement.Parse(doc.DocumentElement.InnerXml);
```

`xElem2` will be `<sub>aaa</sub>`, without(`root`)

**2-** You will get exception if your xml contains text nodes

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<root> text <sub>aaa</sub> </root>");
var xElem1 = XElement.Load(doc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree());
var xElem2 = XElement.Parse(doc.DocumentElement.InnerXml); //<-- XmlException
```

Comment: Thanks for the great solution using `XElement.Load( xmlElement.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree() );`! This is perfect if You need to convert to XElement instances of the `XmlElement` only. But for an `XmlComment` instance `ReadSubtree()` throws: `System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current position of the navigator`.

Comment: For others who would use this approach, make sure that the `NodeType` of all your `XmlNode`s is the `Element`.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using [`InnerXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innerxml(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `XmlElement` to get xml content of your element then parse it to `XElement` using [`XElement.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468714(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static XElement ToXELement(this XmlElement source)
{
    return XElement.Parse(source.InnerXml);
}
```

Comment: Why not use OuterXml instead of InnerXml?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to take over all is to use OuterXml.

```
XElement.Parse(xNode.OuterXml);
```

Another way is to change the outer root element via.

```
XElement.Parse("<NewRoot>" + xNode.InnerXml + "</NewRoot>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this was introduced in a later version of C# ?

```
My_XML_Element = (XmlElement) My_XML_Node;
```

Answer (score -1):

just use it: **XElement** e = **XElement**.Load(node.CreateReader());

I hope that helps.

Example:

[A real code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfLkV.png)
The image code above

> public static XNode GetNodeByFilter(XNode node,ref SortedList filter, int position = 1)
>           {
>
> XNode result = null;
>
> ```
>         if (filter.TryGetValue(position, out XMLSearchCriteria criteria))
>         {
>             while (node != null)
>             {
>                 XElement e = XElement.Load(node.CreateReader());
>                 if (e.Name.LocalName.Equals(criteria.Node) && CheckIfAllAttributesMatch(e.Attributes(), criteria.Attributes))
>                 {
>                     if (++position <= filter.Count)
>                     {
>                         result = GetNodeByFilter(e.FirstNode, ref filter, position);
>                         break;
>                     }
>                     else
>                     {
>                         result = node;
>                     }
>                 }
>
>                 node = node.NextNode;
>             }
>         }
>
>         return result;
>     }
> ```

Answer (score -3):

There actually is a *very* straightforward way to convert an XNode to an XElement:

```
static XElement ToXElement( XNode node)
{
    return node as XElement; // returns null if node is not an XElement
}
```

If you are 100% certain the node is an XElement (or you are prepared to deal with the exception if it is not, then you can simply cast: `(XElement)node`.

Comment: The question is about converting `XmlNode`, not `XNode`.

Answer (score -9):

As far as I know, you can do this:

```
XElement xdoc = new XElement(node.Name, node.InnerXml);
```

Comment: Absolutely no, this will *escape* to whole xml and you will get a single node like `<root> &lt;sub&gt;aaa&lt;/sub&gt; </root>`

Comment: Sorry, but, how do you know his xml is like "<root> <sub>aaa</sub> </root>"? Maybe his nodes are simplier than that.

Comment: Marcos, simpler or not, your code wouldn't work. It escapes and converts all *innerXml* to string. What don't you simply copy and paste my 3-lines code and test it with your solution. No need to discuss about which can be tested easily.

Comment: Your 3 lines? Again, maybe his XML is simplier.

Comment: Marcos, Simpler? more simpler can only be `<tag>aaa</tag>`.  I don't understand what you are trying to say. BTW: Do you say *I posted an answer that would work only for the simplest case* (even it is not correct)

Comment: Root + nodes (1D) and no text nodes.

Comment: Marcos, Your code doesn't work even without any text nodes. Why don't you simply test it? If you read my first comment carefully, it doesn't contain any text node `<root> &lt;sub&gt;aaa&lt;/sub&gt; </root>` This is what you get with my first example.

Comment: It works, of course, with something simplier than your example.

Comment: Marcos, Come on, Please....., It would take your a few minutes. Take my codes, append your solution, open VS and test them with **any** xml you want. **NO YOUR SOLUTION DOESN'T WORK**

Comment: Haha, no need to get fired up. I know you're talking about parsing the full tree, I'm not. I also know InnerHtml is just plain text and the XElement's constructor is not parsing it. In the end, the code can give you an XElement instance from an XmlNode one, so, the code works, that's what I meant.